# SQL Server 2016 Installation: Microsoft .NET Framework installation has failed with exit code 3

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, .net-framework-version

We have a machine of Windows Server 2012 R2.

While installing SQL Server 2016, I get error

> Error installing Microsoft .NET Framework 4.6

I got the software for .NET Framework 4.6 from the team. After installing .NET, I am still facing the same error during installation.

What am I missing?

**Error detail:**

> Action required: Use the following information to resolve the error,
>   and then try the setup process again.
>
> Feature failure reason: An error occurred for a dependency of the
>   feature causing the setup process for the feature to fail.
>
> Error details: § Error installing Microsoft .NET Framework 4.6
>   Microsoft .NET Framework 4.0 installation has failed with exit code 3.
>   Error code: 3 Log file: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\130\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20170125_011558\DotNet46_Cpu64_1.log

Comment: Did you look in the log file?

Comment: @ErikEJ - DotNet46_Cpu64_1.log file says `<span class="r"><span class="t">[1/25/2017, 1:22:53]</span>Exe (D:\d8273a180ac7d9e24f\x64-Windows8.1-KB3045563-x64.cab) failed with 0x3 - The system cannot find the path specified.`. I am not able to understand exactly from log file.